# SSRS Stepped reported based on number

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2, business-intelligence

Using SSRS with SQL Server 2008 R2 (Visual Studio environment).

I am trying to produce a stepped down report based on a level/value in a table on sql server. The level act as a indent position with sort_value been the recursive parent in the report.

Sample of table in SQL Server:

[image: Sample table View]

Sample of output required

[image: Sample Report output view]

Comment: Your problem is that Taps and fittings are both a product. This makes it so you can't split it up this way.

Comment: Is this actual format of the data in the table or is this the result of another query. If it's the result of another query, can you post a sample of the raw data. What you are trying to do is possible I think, it just might be a lot easier if we had better structured data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I've come up with a solution but **please note the following** before you proceed.
1. The process relies on the data being in the correct order, as per your sample data.
2. If this is your real data structure, I strongly recommend you review it.

OK, So the first things I did was recreate your table exactly as per example. I called the table `Stepped` as I couldn't think of anything else!

The following code can then be used as your dataset in SSRS but you can obviously just run the T-SQL directly to see the output.

```
-- Create a copy of the data with a row number. This means the input data MUST be in the correct order.
DECLARE @t TABLE(RowN int IDENTITY(1,1), Sort_Order int, [Level] int, Qty int, Currency varchar(20), Product varchar(20))

INSERT INTO @t (Sort_Order, [Level], Qty, Currency, Product)
    SELECT * FROM Stepped

-- Update the table so each row where the sort_order is NULL will take the sort order from the row above
UPDATE a SET Sort_Order = b.Sort_Order
 FROM @t a
    JOIN @t b on a.RowN = b.rowN+1
 WHERE a.Sort_Order is null and b.Sort_Order is not null

 -- repeat this until we're done.
WHILE @@ROWCOUNT >0
    BEGIN
        UPDATE a SET Sort_Order = b.Sort_Order
            FROM @t a
                JOIN @t b on a.RowN = b.rowN+1
            WHERE a.Sort_Order is null and b.Sort_Order is not null
    END

-- Now we can select from our new table sorted by both sort oder and level.
-- We also separate out the products based on their level.
SELECT 
        CASE Level WHEN 1 THEN Product ELSE NULL END as ProdLvl_1
        , CASE Level WHEN 2 THEN Product ELSE NULL END as ProdLvl_2
        , CASE Level WHEN 3 THEN Product ELSE NULL END as ProdLvl_3
        , QTY
        , Currency
    FROM @t s
    ORDER BY Sort_Order, Level
```

The output looks like this...

[image]

You may also want to consider swapping out the final statement for this.

```
-- Alternatively use this style and use a single column in the report.
-- This is better if the number of levels can change.
SELECT 
        REPLICATE('--', Level-1) + Product  as Product
        , QTY
        , Currency
    FROM @t s
    ORDER BY Sort_Order, Level
```

As this will give you a single column for 'product' indented like this.
[image]